# Missing/Red terrain in Mount and Blade: Fire and Sword

Tags: technical-issues, mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword

Quite often when I play Mount and Blade:With Fire and Sword I will encounter missing or red terrain anywhere in or out of battle. Nothing I have done seems to stop it from occurring and I haven't found anyone else with this problem. I can't figure out how to upload the picture dicrectly but here is a ling to a screenshot I took while playing http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=83429384

Comment: have you tried to verify the integrity of your steam game cache yet?

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: See here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into the game's setup menu and changing the directx settings to run it in DirectX 7.

**Other alternatives:**

- **If you're running an ATI/AMD card**, especially the 4800 series then it could be a problem with your drivers which can be fixed by rolling back or perhaps by updating them.
- **If you're running an Nvidia card** it could be as simple as your graphics card software is overwriting the game's settings.   You need to go into the Nvidia panel (I forget the name of it, it's the equivalent of AMD's CCC) and select "3D Application Controlled".
- **The above suggestion could also be applied to AMD cards** by making sure your Catalyst Control Center isn't applying graphic settings to your games for you.

Comment: Changed it to DirectX 7 and didn't notice any problems! It was on DirectX 9 so I guess that was it.